# Replace Text/Image URL with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, tampermonkey

I am trying to make a custom style for the stylish plugin to use for the Eve Online forums.  I am attempting to resize the avatar image because it was too small for my liking. However it's using a low-quality image and it looks too grainy when resized, so I am trying to figure out how to use the larger image by replacing part of the text, or replacing the url (whatever is easier).  In the image, the only difference a piece of text that shows the size.

See:

meta.eveonline.com/erika_mizune/45/2168_1.png
meta.eveonline.com/erika_mizune/90/2168_1.png

So essentially the 45 (original) needs to be replaced with the 90 in order to look less grainy.

URL to Post: https://meta.eveonline.com/t/avatar-size-category-adjustment/9032

Stylish Plugin: https://userstyles.org/styles/144974/avatar-category-adjustment

My code to resize the image is this:

```html
 .topic-avatar img.avatar
  {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    border-radius: 0;
  }

  .topic-avatar
  {
    width: 75px !important;
  }
```

I tried to search before posting but I'm not finding anything that will work for what I need.

Thanks!

---

Edit 1: I attempted to switch to tampermonkey to use JS as suggested but is not working.  Below is the origional code:

```
    <div class="topic-avatar">
        <a class="trigger-user-card main-avatar" href="/u/Erika_Mizune"
            data-user-card="Erika_Mizune"> <img alt="" width="45" height="45"
            src="https://cdn-enterprise.discourse.org/eveonline/user_avatar/meta.eveonline.com/erika_mizune/45/2168_1.png"
            title="Erika_Mizune" class="avatar"></a>
        <div class="poster-avatar-extra"></div>
    </div>
```

And the script I have in tampermonkey:

```
    var imagelist = document.getElementsByClassName("avatar");
    imagelist.foreach(function(element) {
        element.src = element.src.replace("/45/", "/90/");
    });
```

---

Edit 2: After trying to use debugging in the console I got the error that .foreach is not a function and attempted to try the following as well:

Try 1:

```
var imagelist = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
        imagelist.foreach(function(element) {
            element.src = element.src.replace("/45/", "/90/");
        });
```

Try 2:

```
var imagelist = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('avatar'));
imagelist.foreach(function(element) {
    element.src = element.src.replace("/45/", "/90/");
});
```

Try 3:

```
   var imagelist = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('img'));
imagelist.foreach(function(element) {
    element.src = element.src.replace("/45/", "/90/");
});
```

All of these attempts have returned the same error in console that .foreach is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the javascript solution is the right way to go.

It's really hard to say what's wrong with just a few lines of js from tampermonkey. Is it possible to show the complete files? Or post an example on jsfiddle or something?

It's easy to debug this kind of issue yourself in Chrome Inspector, by typing "debugger" in your code and opening the Source tab in Chrome Inspector (F12 button in Chrome). The inspector will stop at that line and you can see the values of different variables. For example:

First, open Chrome Inspector in Chrome browser. Then load the page with the debugger line:

```
var imagelist = document.getElementsByClassName("forum_image_class");
debugger;
imagelist.foreach(function(element){
    element.src = element.src.replace("/45/", "/90/");
}
```

The browser will stop on the debugger line. Type 'imagelist' into the console and hit enter to see its current value. It might be empty, in which case the getElementsByClassName isnt retrieving anything. Which might be happening for a few different reasons. Or the imagelist array might get populated but the replace() isnt working as expected. Is it possible for you to figure out which is happenng and report it here?

ALSO: be careful with .replace(). You have to escape certain characters with a backslash and you should know what those special characters are. In this case you may or may not need to escape the forward slashes.

Comment: This comes up on the debugger line:imagelist = (7) [div.topic-avatar, div.topic-avatar, div.topic-avatar, div.topic-avatar, div.topic-avatar, div.topic-avatar, div.topic-avatar]

Comment: As for the full file; I have it here: https://pastebin.com/z28NHush (the CSS append works fine, it's just the replacing image that's not working)

Comment: That's great! Click on the first div.topic-avatar link. Then look at the 'src' property. Does it look as you expect it to? Try changing "/45/" and "/90/" just to "45" and "90" for now

Comment: OK, I see the problem. I dont know why your imagelist is returning a bunch of divs. The imagelist array should contain just the imgs. Change the getElementsByClassName arg to "avatar" not "topic-avatar".

Comment: https://pastebin.com/1mRXDzbr

Comment: That pastebin shows one of the 'sub-entries' in the results. img.avatar x27 (which is about the amount of posts viable), each one of those has a dropdown that displays details similar to that pastebin link in previous comment.

Comment: OK thanks,I'm still 100% sure your problem is that imagelist should be <img> nodes, not the <div>s that contain them. I think you're very close to being done

Comment: Readjusted the first line as "getElementsByTagName('img');" but still nothing. :/

Comment: so you know how to use the debugger... add the debugger line inside the foreach and you can click around and see what all the values are for that img. does it have a src property? you can debug this yourself and it's an important skill to pick up

Comment: first check to see if the imagelist is an array of 7

Comment: I can't even get to that point anymore.  Now I am getting "(unknown) ERROR: Execution of script 'EVE Online Forum Avatars' failed! getElementsByTagName is not defined" in the console.  Not sure what that means and google isn't really helping me.

Comment: just go back to getElementsByClassName() with "avatar" as the argument

Comment: I've adjusted the OP with more on the bottom on what I tried. I did get rid of the undefined message, but now I am stuck with .foreach is not a function.

Comment: uggh, try .forEach instead of .foreach?

Comment: Ths is good, we're making progress

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: all right, pretty sure thatll work if you use .forEach(). if you like my answer, plewse mark it is accepted and good luck. you have the basic tools to debug this stuff yourself. just try to read the error messages literally and look up methods in that mozilla reference whenever possible.

Comment: Ah! I should have at least known that! Capitation ... makes a big difference.  Changing that worked. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: yay glad it worked, and now you can use debugger!

Answer (score 0):

Try this? Add `background: url(meta.eveonline.com/erika_mizune/90/2168_1.png) no-repeat !important;` to your img CSS.

```css
.topic-avatar img.avatar {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: url(meta.eveonline.com/erika_mizune/90/2168_1.png) no-repeat !important;
}

.topic-avatar {
  width: 75px !important;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work because that url is just to 'my' avatar.  Everyone has unique avatars. Doing what you posted will make everyone's avatar mine, I don't want that. I need to have the text '45' replaced to '90' in order for it to work for everyone.

Comment: @DJYumene you can do it with JS, not CSS

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to change html content with CSS in the way you're describing. I'd recommend using Javascript to change the `src` of the `<img>` tag. Do something like

```
var imagelist = document.getElementsByClassName("forum_image_class");
imagelist.foreach(function(element){
    element.src = element.src.replace("/45/", "/90/");
}
```

Comment: I added an edit to the OP on what I tried to enter into tampermonkey since it allows JS - didn't work.

Comment: @AJD- .forEach, not .foreach

Comment: 30 second problem for you. 4-hour problem for the OP